# RegEx string splitter

Tags: javascript, regex

What am I doing wrong here? I am trying to extract from this "list"

```
ARTICLE 11 - Title AA
ARTICLE 22 Title BB
ARTICLE 33
ARTICLE 44 - Title DD
ARTICLE 55 Title EE
```

all the article numbers and the titles (if any) for each article.
The "-" is optional when title exists.

With this RegEx

```
(article)(\s*)([^\s]*)((\s*)(-)?(\s*)(.*))
```

I get only 4 items. The item 33 and 44 are considered one article only and this is I suppose just because "ARTICLE 33" has no title.

```
11|Title AA
22|Title BB
33|ARTICLE 44 - Title DD
55|Title EE
```

Please see the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z94wf/

**EDIT**

What I expect to get is this:

```
11|Title AA
22|Title BB
33|
44|Title DD
55|Title EE
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You second `\s*` is matching the newline char on the 3rd line, so if you change to explicitly match only space and dash as follows

```
(article)(\s*)([^\s]+)(([ -]*)(.*))
```

you get the desired result

http://jsfiddle.net/Z94wf/37/

Answer (score 2):

I can't be sure on all of the forms of your input but what about something with a few less groups and a bit more explicit...

```
ARTICLE\s+(\d+)[\s-]*(.*)
```

This should match the starting literal followed by some space followed by the number and then an optional set of spaces and the "-" char and then everything else.

Comment: This is returning exactly the same result.

Comment: @Andrew White - if you plug this into the provided jsfiddle sandbox you do not get the desired result.

Comment: @cordsen: I didn't realize I was supposed to use jsfiddler (never have before). At this point it's a matter of just checking \2 to see if it's empty or not.

Comment: @Andrew White - What I mean is that your solution does not work the second `\s` matches the newline in line 3 just like the original expression. I don't think using jsfillde is required but it was provided by the OP as an easy way to test before posing an answer.

Comment: @cordsen: yeah the \s matches the newline BUT this also means the \2 group will be empty which can easily be tested for when building up the list. In any case, he has as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var s = $('#in').val();
    var re = /(article)(\s)([0-9][0-9])((\s|-)*)/gi;
    $('#out1').val(s.replace(re,'$3|$5'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Z94wf/35/

Comment: This returns a space before the title

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var s = $('#in').val();
    var re = /article\s*(\d+)[ -]*(.*)/gi;
    $('#out1').val(s.replace(re,'$1|$2'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var s = $('#in').val();
    var re = /^article\s+([^\s]+)(?:$|\s*(-\s*)?)/gmi;
    $('#out1').val(s.replace(re,'$1|'));
});
```

to get your output.

You can see working demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/Z94wf/76/

Comment: This returns a space before the title

Answer (score 1):

For tracking down issues like this, I find the Regex Powertoy to be very helpful. You can enter sample text and regular expressions and suss out a lot about how the matches are working (or not working). Super-handy:

http://regex.powertoy.org/

Comment: Thanks for the tool. I got used with "The Regex Coach"... At the end, tool matters only if you know what to do with it :) I my case, the tool was doing the right job...